# Question about Decision boundary in Logistical Regression

Tags: logistic, classification, optimization, convex

I am a Machine Learning newbie and studying Logistical Regression.

[image: Red cross = Class 1 and Blue Circle = Class 2]

For the data shown above, a straight line cannot separate all the positive and negative decisions. One thing I could understand is that I would need a higher order polynomial such as
θ<sub>0</sub> + θ<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + θ<sub>2</sub>x<sub>2</sub> + θ<sub>3</sub>x<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub> + θ<sub>4</sub>x<sup>2</sup><sub>2</sub>

But consider that, prediction is h<sub>θ</sub>(x) = 1/(1 + e<sup>- z</sup>) where z = θ<sub>0</sub> + θ<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + θ<sub>2</sub>x<sub>2</sub> (a straight line) and the cost equation is -y.log(h<sub>θ</sub>(x)) + (1 -y).log(1 - h<sub>θ</sub>(x)). For this cost equation, whenever h<sub>θ</sub>(x) tends to 1 and y is 0 OR whenever h<sub>θ</sub>(x) tends to 0 and y is 1, the cost tends to infinity.

So my questions are:

1. Will the above mentioned cost function be a convex function?
2. If we use gradient descent, will it converge to global minimum?

I think that gradient descent will not converge as the cost tends to infinity whenever prediction and actual do not match. Whether I am correct or wrong, please help with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h_\theta(x)$ can never be $0$ or $1$ for real $x$. And, logistic regression is known to be a convex optimisation problem when cross-entropy loss is used, which means the cost is a convex function wrt parameters. Since the problem is convex, gradient descent can be used to approach the global optimum arbitrarily close, while typical implementations use second-order optimisation methods.

Note: logistic regression will create a linear decision boundary again. $h(x)$ has nothing to do with feature transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @gunes. I have made some edits based on your comment and also mentioned the use of straight line for separation. If possible, can you consider the edits to answer the questions?

Comment: @Amit my answer stands. note that you can't make $h$ as $0$ or $1$ using any value of z.

Comment: As I understand from your comment, the cost function will always be convex and gradient descent will converge even if we use a straight line for separation. Of course, I do understand that a straight line is a wrong choice for classification in this problem.

Comment: that is correct

Comment: Thanks so much @gunes for the answer and the clarification.